# Segmentation fault in Dijkstra in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra

I am trying to learn Dijkstra's Algorithm but the code gives me segmentation fault. I am not getting why this code is giving me segmentation fault.

I want to implement this algorithm using class and vector, so this is my approach to the code, I got the algorithm pseudo code from `g4g` .

This is the line where the segmentation fault is given, if statement in below code.

```
if(!sptset[v] && adj[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX 
       && dist[u] + adj[u][v] < dist[v])
```

And this is the member function

```
void Graph::Dijkstra(int src) {
  int dist[V];
  bool sptset[V];
  for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptset[i] = false;
  dist[src] = 0;
  //find shortest path for all vertices
  for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++) {
    int u = MinDistance(dist, sptset);
    sptset[u] = true;
    //update dist value of the ajacent vertices
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
        if (!sptset[v] && adj[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX
                && dist[u] + adj[u][v] < dist[v])
            dist[v] = dist[u] + adj[u][v];
    }
 }
```

}

Class graph is declared as below

```
class Graph(){
  int V;
  vector<int> *adj;
};
```

Here is full code if any one wants to see . [Ideone](http://ideone.com/jHlybx)
Please help me to understand why this error is given. and where is mistake, that I am not getting the code to work.

** Edit answer. **

This is where I was wrong in the code. The `adj` is vector and got variable size, I considered like an array so I looped it till `V` that should be changed to `adj[u].size()` so that it loops only through it. Thanks for help

```
for (int v = 0; v < adj[u].size(); v++) {
        if (!sptset[v] && adj[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX
                && dist[u] + adj[u][v] < dist[v])
            dist[v] = dist[u] + adj[u][v];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your graph adjacency is not stored in a full matrix. From the **linked** code seems that `adj[v]` is a `std::vector` containing only the index of adjacents to `v`. In the **posted** algorithm instead it's used like if it was a full `V*V` matrix of bool values.